# How to make the two buttons center?

Tags: android

I have set  android:gravity="center" for the two buttons both btnDelete and btnClose.
but I still find the two button is on left-side , how can I do ? Thanks!

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvBody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"       
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="1dip"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:text="" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adViewabout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvOnlyFullSpace"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/myreturn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: style="@style/myTextAppearance" ? which type of parameters did you use in it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Add gravity:center to LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    style="@style/myTextAppearance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/delete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    style="@style/myTextAppearance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/myreturn" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code is OK, but I'm still surprising I have added android:layout_gravity="center" for button in my code, why don't the button center?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add gravity to the layout not the Button, gravity in button settings is for Text inside the button

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm still surprising I have added android:layout_gravity="center" for button in my code, why can't the button be center?